# what does the standard deviation plot around my learning curve indicate?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, training

I plotted a learning curve below. There is a thick red band around the top portion of my training score. Why is it so high at the beginning?

[image]

Below is a snippet of the code used:

```
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes, scoring= 'neg_brier_score')
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                     color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                     # + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Training brier score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Cross-validation brier score")
```

Answer (score 0):

I only have a guess, but I suspect it could be simply due to random initialisation. This would mean that after few training samples the models would still be very different. After 400k training samples the models all converge to the same learning path. I could be wrong of course!

Comment: For a small number of training examples, the variance in the different learned models is still higher.